# Защита от DDOS 2 машины.

Tags: ddos, защита, debian, linux

Есть такая идея:
Имеются 2 тачки.
1 На ней висят сайт и сервер авторизация(моей программы).
2 На ней висит сама программа, к этой тачке открыт всего 1 порт для пользователей.
Цель:
На первой тачке открыть порт(такой же как на 2) и если к этому порту обратятся сразу кидать в бан. 
Но как сделать так, чтобы и на второй тачке ip был забанен, как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: А что мешает организовать взаимодействие двух хостов? Если вы занимаетесь сетевым программированием, вопросов возникать не должно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDOS атакой свалят вашу первую тачку (с веб-сервером и сервером авторизации) и на вторую авторизаванные пользователи уже не попадут. Ищите датацентр с аппаратной защитой от ДДОС атак, например, Оверсан.

Потом нужно понимать, что хорошая DDOS атака дорога в реализации.

Answer (score 1):

Если еще актуально, могу помочь в настройке nginx + iptables или посоветую аппаратную защиту проксированием.

Comment: Пару способов имеется, но все же вопрос еще актуален!